# How to disable database connection while installation script is running in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, database

I'm building a custom installation script for a Laravel application but I get a QueryException when I try to execute the script:
`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'demo_app.users' doesn't exist`

This is understandable since the database `demo_app` is empty until the migrations have been executed by the installation script.

Is there a way I can use to disable the database connection check during the installation process? Some thing like this:

if($appIsNotInstalled){
# disable database connection
}else{
# allow database connection
}

I hope the issue is clear and thanks in advance

Comment: This is because something in your service provider call database. Find this place and bypass, for example, static variable in your script (Installer::isInstalled())

Comment: I thought that much but I wasn't able to locate the call to the database

Comment: If you cannot locate problem - you cannot solve them.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I think an installation script should run composer install first, then php artisan migrate. This way there is no way that your migrations won't run.

Comment: The user should insert the database name and other configurations during the installation process before migrating. That's the issue

Comment: So if I get this right, then the user input values will got into the .env file right? Do the migrations run if you just simply edit the .env file and run the installation process by hand (e.g. composer install then artisan migrate)? Also what kind of script is this? Bash or artisan command, python? Could you give a bit more insight, please.

Comment: It's a PHP script. And you got it right, the values will be saved to the .env file, and the migrations are run using the `Artisan::call()` method. Also, the composer is already installed before the installation script. The user is supposed to upload the app and run the installation script on their server

Comment: If you could insert logs in the script then you could debug on what step it exits. Can the script start running the migrations at all?  Because based on your question it looks like that the database access has been configured fine and there is interaction with the database(e.g. base table not found). I would also check if there are DB seeders that might conflict with the migrations.

Comment: I'll do that and thanks for your time. I appreciate it

Comment: I ended up creating a new laravel project from scratch and the issue is fixed. Thanks